# Application migration from .net core 2.1 to 3.0

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.0

I'm trying to upgrade my project to .net core 3.0 when it used to be running with asp core 2.1.

The application compile fine but as soon as i start it, the application crash on the app.usespa() function in startup.cs ...

Does someone has already encountered this issue ? 
When i create a sample project from scratch with angular it runs well ...

Thanks in advance,
Razgort

Comment: Did you also update the spa libraries to 3.x?

Comment: Is there any error in the output? Share us the content in your .csproj. It would be helpful if there is a demo to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

One of your library is still not upgraded to 3.x.
use NUGET to update all your libraries to be compatible with 3.x